# How to fix truncated y-axis and x-axis

Tags: d3.js

After rotating the x-axis and y-axis label it has become truncated - to fix the truncated x-axis and y-axis please advise how to fix it on d3.js platform. I am completely lost how to make the x-axis and y-axis to show all the words dynamically and dynamically shrink the chart accordingly

```
var margin = {top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40},
    width = pbi.width - margin.left - margin.right,   // ALTER: Changed fixed width with the 'pbi.width' variable
    height = pbi.height - margin.top - margin.bottom; // ALTER: Changed fixed height with the 'pbi.height' variable

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.9);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// ALTER: Replaced the d3.tsv function with the pbi variant: pbi.dsv
pbi.dsv(type, function(wwo) {
    x.domain(wwo.map(function(d) { return d.wwo; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(wwo, function(d) { return d.activity_duration; })]);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"))
        .selectAll("text")
           .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)")
           .style("text-anchor", "end");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(wwo)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .style("fill", pbi.colors[0]) // First color of provided color array
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.wwo); })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.activity_duration); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.activity_duration); });
});

function type(d) {
    d.activity_duration = +d.activity_duration;
    return d;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Increasing `margin.bottom` should do the trick.

Comment: lol u damn right never expect.. but how to do this dynamically ...because the data not always long label sometimes it is short....so if the margin is fixed then even if the label short it will still shrink

Comment: *Truncated axis* means a completely different thing in data visualisation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase your margin in this case, so increasing the value of `margin.bottom` will decrease the size of the chart content, and leave more space between the bottom of the container and the Y-axis.

If you aren't sure how long your titles are going to be and you are doing this client side (rather than a server side rendered chart) then you can take advantage of [getBBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) and a double render to automatically size.

You can render your chart as is, then use `getBBox()` to calculate the height of each of those labels. Take the largest one and use this as your `margin.bottom`. Then re-render the chart with the new size.